# MySQL TRIM spaces inside text

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a DB with users table. One of the fields is cellphone, but is as VARCHAR type.
Some users modify their phone with correct and desired behavior, a number without spaces. But other users just add it and let spaces between chars.

```
Desired data:
5354663598

Some cases:
53 5 466 3598
```

In PHP I can solve this with a foreach, and later a `str_replace(" ", "", $user->cellphone);`

But I just want to know if there is a MySQL function for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhmm, solved!, thanks Ferenc Kurucz.

```
UPDATE users SET phone = REPLACE(phone," ","")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html):

```
REPLACE(str, find_string, replace_with)
```

Comment: Complete query please! something like UPDATE users REPLACE(phone," ","")